# Is there a way to check nested workbooks for specific worksheets and list out or mark those workbooks not containing the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to save time in looking for excel files without a specific sheet named "RUNREADY" in a large directory of nested folders and excel files. This workbook without the worksheet would ideally be listed in a master excel file higher up in the directory or just have its name changed to end in a '(1)' or '(0)' depending on if it has the sheet or not.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"
'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents
'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
  'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code



  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rr As Integer
  Dim cel As Range
  rr = 0
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "RUNREADY" Then
            rr = rr + 1
        Else
            rr = 0
        End If
  Next ws
  If rr = 1 Then
    [RUNREADY.xlsm] Sheet1!cel.Value = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    [RUNREADY.xlsm] Sheet1!cel.Offset(1, 0)
  End If



'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"
ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I looked around for some sort of guidance and found this piece of code that searches through a file. I tried to write something that would write to a named excel file. my portion is spaced off in the middle of everything Running this i get an error at the first square bracket in my portion of code.

Comment: Which part of this is giving you problems?  What did you try and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: "Running this i get an error at the first square bracket in my portion of code." What is the error? What is that part of the code supposed to do? Why have you used square brackets? Why did we have to search for square brackets in the lengthy code? I suspect that if you can answer those questions, you will find your own answer.

Comment: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`, `If ws.Name <> "RUNREADY" Then`... you list rr = 0 in the false... if the last worksheet in the workbook is not "RunReady" then you will return 0.  Fix the logic for that section.  Inside of the loop, add to `rr`, outside of the loop use `rr` then set it to `0`.

Comment: also, `[RUNREADY.xlsm] Sheet1!cel.Value = ActiveWorkbook.FullName` is not correct syntax... something like `Workbook("RUNREADY.XLSM").Sheets("Sheet1").cel.value` would be more appropriate